# atd reports Permission denied

Tags: shell

After scheduling jobs to be run later using `at`, at the given time `atd` will report "Permission denied" instead of starting the jobs. The permissions for /var/spool/cron/at* are correct:

```
root@server /var/spool/cron # ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root    4096 Okt 30  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root    4096 Okt 30  2014 ..
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Nov  1 17:57 atjobs
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Nov  1 17:57 atspool
drwx-wx--T 2 root   crontab 4096 Nov  1 17:34 crontabs
```

When running the command sent to `at` manually, all will work fine.

Comment: Is `"Permission denied"` the full error message you get? Isn't there more? If there is, please include. Tiny details may look irrelevant to you, but might be crucial to debugging. Also, please add an example command that you try to run with `at` and fails, and more details about how exactly you schedule it, and how exactly you run it manually.

Comment: @janos I am running `atd -d` (debug) to see what is going on. `Permission denied` is shown as soon as the planned time arrives and the command is trying to run. I am running `echo "commands" | at $TIME` to queue them. The same set of commands runs fine when called up directly. I do know that `at` uses `sh` while I am using `bash`, but my commands also run fine in `sh`.

Comment: As a sanity check, can you try a very simply command to run, say `date > /tmp/date`. My suspicion is that this will work fine, and the problem is with some specific commands. For example, if the command is a shell script on your user's encrypted drive that is not accessible by the owner of the `atd` process, that would explain the permission denied error. This is just an example. I think we need more details about the commands that you are running, and if they are accessible by the owner of `atd`.

Comment: @janos `echo "date > /tmp/date" | at 13:38` was my cmd now. `atq` said this: `26 Mon Nov 13 13:38:00 2017 a root`. After the time passed, it looked like this: `26 Mon Nov 13 13:38:00 2017 = root`. The cmd `cd /tmp; ls` shows this: `adminer.invalid  adminer.key  ssh-AxuZ39xUcg` but no `date` file. The task stays active (`=` entry). `tail /var/log/syslog` tells this: `Nov 13 13:38:00 srv atd[19110]: Permission denied`.

Comment: @janos Noteworthy is that `syslog` also shows `CRON` lines with `Permission denied` whysoever, although cron is an unrelated system to `at`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question; it might be better for [unix.se]. You can flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate it.

Comment: Its possible that when you run it manually, you are a root user as shown. But when you run it with `at`, you maybe using another user without the required permissions.

Comment: How to know the user that it is run as?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any OS specs, my suspicion is that SELinux could be at play.

Check if it's enabled: `getenforce` would return `Enforcing`.  If yes, then as root, run `setenforce permissive`, then see if your command runs without permission denied errors.

Comment: getenforce: Command not found.

Comment: Can you tell us what OS you're running?  I'm assuming it's Linux...if so, what distro?

Also, `getenforce` might just not be in your `$PATH`.  Try `/usr/sbin/getenforce`.

Comment: It’s Debian jessie. `find / -name getenforce` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for answers on why `atd` was running but jobs failed to executed with the following in the journal:

```
Nov 16 05:28:00 yourserver atd[15038]: Cannot create output file: Permission denied
```

The system is Debian 10 buster.

One thing I noted is that the `atd` process was running as the `daemon` user which lead me to: [Why does Debian run "atd" as the "daemon" user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532625)

OK, fine.

It turns out that `man atd` had some useful info in the FILES section.

```
       /var/spool/cron/atjobs The directory for storing jobs; this should be mode 700, owner daemon.

       /var/spool/cron/atspool The directory for storing output; this should be mode 700, owner daemon.
```

Once I'd ensured those directory's had those permissions and ownership, things started to work as expected.

For this particular system, I assume that `at` was not regularly in use and this system (so the issue wasn't caught until now). The system has been upgraded over years from much older Debian versions, so it looks like those directories never received the correct (updated) permissions and ownership when the change from running `atd` as root to daemon happened.